# Getting unhandled ArgumentException when starting a new thread for a method of an instanced class

Tags: c#, winforms

I have class `HBClient` which contains `connect()` method.

```
        public void connect()
    {
      //connect to TCP socket
    }
```

This is a winform, and I create instances of my `Form1` and `HBClient` as such.

//Program.CS

```
        Form1 form = new Form1();
        HBClient hbClient = new HBClient();
```

//Form1.CS

```
    //Form1 Class
    public HBClient hbClient;

    public void GetClient(HBClient receivedHBClient)
    {
        hbClient = receivedHBClient;
    }


    //HBClient Class
    public  Form1 form;

    public void GetForm(Form1 receivedForm)
    {
        form = receivedForm;
    }
```

and link them together...

```
        hbClient.GetForm(form);
        form.GetClient(hbClient);
```

When my form tries to call `hbClient.connect` in a thread, I get an `unhandled ArgumentException`.

```
        Thread thread = new Thread(hbClient.connect);
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();
```

> "Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'."

Comment: From a design perspective, you should decouple HBClient from your UI. The HBClient should not have any knowledge of what class instantiated it. In other words, it should never call receivedForm.Something().

Comment: What happens if you just drop a button on your form, and call `hbClient.connect()` from it?

Comment: Final question -- what class is HBClient using under the hood? If socket, any reason you're not using [ConnectAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.connectasync(v=vs.110).aspx)? If WebClient, any reason you aren't using its async methods?

Comment: What event on your form is trying to start up the thread?

Comment: @MartinBrown It's in the constructor for Form1().

Comment: @LynnCrumbling If I map the .connect() to a button, the same error occurs.

Comment: You should add a call stack dump to your question.

Comment: Guys, I figured it out... I'm being dumb. I was calling `hbClient.connect()`  in the `Form1` constructor, which happens before Form1's `getClient()`... which means `hbClient` didn't exist yet.

Sorry to waste your time :/